# Shell Script program to execute all pdf files in one folder to convert them in .xml or .json format and save the output in another folder

Tags: linux, unix

I'm in of need of help.
How do i write a shell script program using Apache Tika as the converter to help me execute .pdf files in one directory and save them in another directory in a different format (json, xml, etc).

Comment: You'd get better answers if you showed your work -- demonstrated what you had tried and how it failed, for instance, or precisely which part of the process you're having trouble with.

Comment: ...indeed, I've written up an answer, but almost hesitate to post it to avoid rewarding bad behavior (the bad behavior in question being a "please write my code for me" question with no evidence of effort to build a solution yourself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rough example, using JSON:

```
outdir=../out.d
mkdir -p "$outdir"
for f in *.pdf; do
  java -jar tika-app.jar --json "$f" >"$outdir/${f%.pdf}.json" \
    || rm -- "$outdir/${f%.pdf}.json"
done
```

Obviously, this expects `tika-app.jar` to be in the current directory; adjust to taste. Similarly, see http://tika.apache.org/1.6/gettingstarted.html for full command-line usage.

To understand the `${f%.pdf}` shell syntax, see [BashFAQ #73](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073).